# Microphone code doesn't run on iPhone device

Tags: iphone, microphone

I am trying to run the following code on my device with no success. Although the code works perfectly on Simulator. I have been following this tutorial. It simply crash on device.

http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-detecting-when-a-user-blows-into-the-mic/

Code is:

```
@interface MicBlowViewController : UIViewController {
    AVAudioRecorder *recorder;
    NSTimer *levelTimer;
    double lowPassResults;
}
- (void)levelTimerCallback:(NSTimer *)timer;
@end
```

.m file :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/dev/null"];
    NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0],                 AVSampleRateKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless], AVFormatIDKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1],                         AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMax],         AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                              nil];
    NSError *error;
    recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:settings error:&error];
    if (recorder)
    {
        [recorder prepareToRecord];
        recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
        [recorder record];
        levelTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 3 
                                                      target: self 
                                                    selector: @selector(levelTimerCallback:) 
                                                    userInfo: nil 
                                                     repeats: YES];
    } 
    else
        NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);
}

- (void)levelTimerCallback:(NSTimer *)timer {
    [recorder updateMeters];
    const double ALPHA = 0.05;
    double peakPowerForChannel = pow(10, (0.05 * [recorder peakPowerForChannel:0]));
    lowPassResults = ALPHA * peakPowerForChannel + (1.0 - ALPHA) * lowPassResults;  
    if (lowPassResults < 0.95)
        NSLog(@"Mic blow detected");
}
```

Comment: What does the crash log tell you ?

Comment: I don't see any error in this code except for memory management and don't forget that NSTimer retains its target so you need to reset timer outside your dealloc method. Try to post more code or crash log

Comment: I don't think there is any problem with NSTimer. As you can see in the log output above

Comment: This is the 1st line of log.

unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.yourcompany.MicBlow[0xe0ef]) Job appears to have crashed: Bus error

Answer (score 1):

Add those two lines of code after   [recorder prepareToRecord ]

```
    [recorder prepareToRecord];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
```